# Newton polygon and asymptotic behavior near a singular point

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, asymptotics

As we know, Newton polygons could be used to determine the Puiseux series of algebraic curves (see, for example, Kirwan's *Complex Algebraic Curves*, chapter 7). Different branches correspond to different Puiseux series, then the asymptotic behavior of such a branch could be seen from the Puiseux series. However, I need to determine the asymptotic behavior of a general curve $F(x,y)=0$ near $(0,0)$ where $F\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is a smooth ($\mathcal C^\infty$) function and $F(0,0)=0$. Suppose that the Taylor series of $F$ is $\sum_{j,k\ge0}a_{jk}x^jy^k\in\mathbb R[[x,y]]$ (might be divergent), and the Newton polygon is depicted as the lower convex hull of the degrees of nonzero terms: $\{\,(m,n)\,\colon\,a_{mn}\neq0\,\}$. Can we still claim that the asymptotic behavior ($y\sim x^\alpha$, etc) of branches of the curve $F(x,y)=0$ near the singular point $(0,0)$ follows from such a Newton diagram?

As a very simple case, if $\partial F/\partial x,\partial F/\partial y$ don't vanish at $(0,0)$, then the asymptotic behavior of $F(x,y)=0$ near $(0,0)$ is (non-degenerately) linear, following from the implicit function theorem, which coincides the information given by the Newton diagram.